# Map with Advanced datagrid in flex

Tags: actionscript-3, flex3

I had a map like

Map** helloMethos()
{

}

I need to display the values to the advanced datagrid with the Map.

I had searched, Advanced Atagrid supports only list of Arraycollection to display the values in grid. is it Correct?
Please help me out if am wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you should write a converter from your Map class to `ArrayCollection` class.
If you'll share your `Map` class source, I will help you.